# How to work with href in MVC4? I am getting stuck there

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url, visual-studio-2012, href

Here I created two controllers in MVC project.
1)Home
2)Register
when I build solution and run project ,in first step code works and I get desire output, then I click on a link it redirects to another page , this is also my desire output but just when again click on a link(href) it don't show desire output and rewrite values of both URLs in URL bar of browser.
Here is well explanation of my problem.
[image: In first attempt]
[image: Second attempt]
[image: Here when I try again through href link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost:6116/Register/Home/Index URL is wrong.

Your method must return an ActionResult. Usually, it's a ViewResult when you use return View(), but if you want to redirect to another action, there is another return type.

`return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");`